# How Strict is the rule no dom manipulation inside controller in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, dom

I know in AngularJS We are not supposed to do any dom manipulation inside a controller. But If i need to do a dom manipulation on click of an element then how am i supposed to handle it. For example while building a menu i need to show submenu on click how do i accomplish it without dom manipulation in the controller?

Comment: You can use `ng-show` and `ng-hide`. Create a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8LUaaEumbSVvKkgTQLtS?p=preview)

Comment: hi Satpal, would have used ng-show but the menu is data driven. I have alreday created the menu using a directive. you can find the code in this [pos](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19907763/creating-elements-dynamically-in-angular/19908036?noredirect=1#comment29624906_19908036)